# Jquery datatable: Removing row redirects to first page every time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am using below code to remove the row and paint the table again:

```
var table= $('#datatable').DataTable();
var row = //tr element
table.row(row).remove().draw();
```

I want to remove the row but at the same time I want to remain in the same page instead it goes to first page now.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `draw(false)` instead.

> Also shown is the row().remove() method which deletes a row from a table, and the draw() method with false as its first parameter. [This will redraw the table keeping the current paging](https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html) (without the false parameter the paging would be reset to the first page).